# Computer tools to solve linear system of equations with singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, wolfram-alpha, python

According to the theory I've read, if $A$ is singular, the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ will have either zero or infinitely many solutions. I tried solving this equation for:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 4 & 3 \\
-4 & -4 & -3 \\
3 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix},
b=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Solving by hand gives $x=[-1, 1, 0] * x_2 + [-1, 0, 1]$. So one solution for $x_2 = 0$ would be $[-1, 0, 1]$ which works.

When I try to solve it using WolframAlpha, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7B%7B4%2C4%2C3%7D%2C%7B-4%2C-4%2C-3%7D%2C%7B3%2C3%2C3%7D%7Db%20%3D%20%7B-1%2C1%2C0%7D), it says no solutions exists. When I try to solve it in python using `np.linalg.solve`, I get `LinAlgError: Singular matrix`.

How can I solve this type of equation for singular matrices using python or WolframAlpha? How come several computer programs how problems with this kind of equation?

Comment: are you just looking for any solution?

Comment: All solutions would be better.

Comment: @Moo: Thanks that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For symbolic computation the easiest way is to use rref:

```
In [74]: from sympy import Matrix
In [75]: Matrix([[4,4,3,-1],[-4,-4,-3, 1],[3,3,3,0]]).rref()[0]                                                                                                        
Out[75]: Matrix([
         [1, 1, 0, -1],
         [0, 0, 1,  1],
         [0, 0, 0,  0]])
```

And in Wolfram Alpha like this: `rref{{4,4,3,-1},{-4,-4,-3,1},{3,3,3,0}}`

Taking the LU decomposition only gets you halfway there, and it is easier to use rref in my opinion.

For numerical (floating point), which is what numpy uses, the two other answers gives the best way. This is because floating point calculations doesn't give exact answers, so some way to get an approximation is needed. This is done with different variants of the least-squares method.

[Here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Reduced-row-echelon-form-td16486.html) is a discussion about why numpy does not include rref.

Comment: Both other answers give highly accurate solutions (at least more accurate than your answer). You never asked about *all* solutions, but two other methods  that work with numpy are using the LU decomposition (U is in row echelon form), or using one of the methods from the answers to get a general solution, and then constructing the null space with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835246/how-to-solve-homogeneous-linear-equations-with-numpy) method.

Comment: As I understand it rref, when using symbolic computation, gives the exact solution. How can any other method give a more accurate solution? What is the advantage of the more complicated solutions, unless you are doing numerical (floating point) computation?

Comment: Sympy does not always perform symbolic computation. For example, Matrix([[1, 1e20, 1], [1, 1e20, 0], [0, 1, 1]]).det() gives $0$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good gotcha to keep in mind. In order for sympy to do symbolic computation you should feed it integers and not floats: `Matrix([[1, 1*10^20, 1], [1, 1*10^20, 0], [0, 1, 1]]).det()` gives 1.

Comment: And use for example S(1)/3 to do symbolic computations with fractions. One could also use sympy's arbitrary precision Float class, which I think should also give exact answers with rref, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to this problem, I will use the concept of a pseudo-inverse described here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

```
import numpy as np

# initialize singular matrix and rhs vector
A = np.array([\
             [4., 4., 3.],\
             [-4., -4., -3.],\
             [3., 3., 3.]\
             ])
b = np.array([-1., 1., 0.])

# compute the pseudo inverse of A
# computationally intensive for large problems
Apinv = np.linalg.pinv(A)

# apply the pseudo-inverse to the rhs
# vector to obtain the `solution'
x = Apinv.dot(b)
print(x)
```

When I ran the above code, I obtained the solution `[-0.5,-0.5,1.0]`,
which can be verified by hand that it is a solution. You can use
the same solution method in Mathematica by calling the `PseudoInverse[]`
function (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PseudoInverse.html) and pass the array as argument and the pseudoinverse will be returned.

Comment on square systems: while if the matrix is singular it is possible to have nonunique solutions of the linear system, the pseudo inverse of a singular matrix is unique.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve such a problem is to ask for the solution $x$ with the smallest norm. The solution of $\min\{x^Tx : Ax=b\}$ can be obtained via the Lagrangian, and corresponds to the solution of:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}2I & A^T \\ A & O \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ b\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
For the general solution, you could compute the LU decomposition of $A$, and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to read up a bit on linear algebra in order to understand it.

Comment: @sirius123 did you eventually read up on linear algebra?

Comment: I did, see my answer below.